# How to fix this script in order to get the correct output?

Tags: regex, bash

Hello everyone I am writing a script that process a text, the text looks as follows:

```
"TW|223SDSDr33|Archive" "Yes"
"TW|ASFFSDFSFASDFS|Name" "LOCALggr"
"TW|AFFSFSFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckAssocCd" ""
"TW|12AFFFSDFASFSFASDFS|AFFAckCommID" "fsdf"
"TW|FSFASFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckLevel" "fsdf Supported"
"TW|AFFSDFAASFSA|AFFAckRqst" "No Requedfst"
"TW|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckTestInd" "Test"
"TW|sfasfsSFSAFAS|AFFAckVersion" "fsdfs"
"TW|sfasfsSFSAFAS|AFFCharSet" "13A"
"TW|sfasfsSFSAFAS|AFFICCheckCtlNo" ""
"TW|AFSFFASFASSFA13A13|AFFICCheckCtlNo" "fsdf"
"TW|sfasfsSFSAFAS|AFFICLstRcvdCtlNo" "fsdfs"
```

The idea is to run this code as follows:

```
bash script.sh --string1 AFFICCheckCtlNo --string2 hola --text text.txt
```

And the desired output it´s this:

```
"TW|223SDSDr33|Archive" "Yes"
"TW|ASFFSDFSFASDFS|Name" "LOCALggr"
"TW|AFFSFSFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckAssocCd" ""
"TW|12AFFFSDFASFSFASDFS|AFFAckCommID" "fsdf"
"TW|FSFASFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckLevel" "fsdf Supported"
"TW|AFFSDFAASFSA|AFFAckRqst" "No Requedfst"
"TW|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckTestInd" "Test"
"TW|sfasfsSFSAFAS|AFFAckVersion" "fsdfs"
"TW|sfasfsSFSAFAS|AFFCharSet" "13A"
"TW|sfasfsSFSAFAS|AFFICCheckCtlNo" "hola"
"TW|AFSFFASFASSFA13A13|AFFICCheckCtlNo" "hola"
"TW|sfasfsSFSAFAS|AFFICLstRcvdCtlNo" "fsdfs"
```

The first parameter after the flag --string1 is a string that we want to find in the line where will be changed the value after this string, the value withing the quotes, and the value after the flag --string2 it´s the new value, the value after the flag --text is the name of the file that contains the information, in order to achieve this I tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
function menu () {
        while (($# >= 1))
        do
        key="$1"
        case $key in
                --text)
                text=$2
                shift
                ;;
                --string1)
                string1=$2
                shift
                ;;
                --string2)
                string2=$2
                shift
                ;;
        esac
        shift
        done
}
function replaceString () {
        cat "$1" | sed -e 's/\("[\w\|]+\|'"$2"'"\) "[\w ]*"/\1 '\""$3"\"'/g' > newText.txt
        cat newText.txt
}
menu "$@"
replaceString $text $string1 $string2
```

I ran it as follows:

```
bash script.sh --string1 AFFICCheckCtlNo --string2 hola --text text.txt
```

And I got:

```
"TW|223SDSDr33|Archive" "Yes"
"TW|ASFFSDFSFASDFS|Name" "LOCALggr"
"TW|AFFSFSFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckAssocCd" ""
"TW|12AFFFSDFASFSFASDFS|AFFAckCommID" "fsdf"
"TW|FSFASFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckLevel" "fsdf Supported"
"TW|AFFSDFAASFSA|AFFAckRqst" "No Requedfst"
"TW|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckTestInd" "Test"
"TW|sfasfsSFSAFAS|AFFAckVersion" "fsdfs"
"TW|sfasfsSFSAFAS|AFFCharSet" "13A"
"TW|sfasfsSFSAFAS|AFFICCheckCtlNo" "hola"
"TW|AFSFFASFASSFA13A13|AFFICCheckCtlNo" "fsdf"
"TW|sfasfsSFSAFAS|AFFICLstRcvdCtlNo" "fsdfs"
```

I successfully changed one line as I wished, but just one line, I want to change all the lines that have the same conditions as in the example, I also made other examples ruining my code as:

```
bash script.sh --string1 AFFCharSet --string2 hola --text text.txt
```

And I got:

```
"TW|223SDSDr33|Archive" "Yes"
"TW|ASFFSDFSFASDFS|Name" "LOCALggr"
"TW|AFFSFSFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckAssocCd" ""
"TW|12AFFFSDFASFSFASDFS|AFFAckCommID" "fsdf"
"TW|FSFASFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckLevel" "fsdf Supported"
"TW|AFFSDFAASFSA|AFFAckRqst" "No Requedfst"
"TW|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckTestInd" "Test"
"TW|sfasfsSFSAFAS|AFFAckVersion" "fsdfs"
"TW|sfasfsSFSAFAS|AFFCharSet" "13A"
"TW|sfasfsSFSAFAS|AFFICCheckCtlNo" ""
"TW|AFSFFASFASSFA13A13|AFFICCheckCtlNo" "fsdf"
"TW|sfasfsSFSAFAS|AFFICLstRcvdCtlNo" "fsdfs"
```

the script did not any changes, I don't known if this is a problem related to my regular expression, I would like to appreciate any suggestion to fix my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` doesn't support `\w`. Use`[:alnum:]` instead (if supported).

Also, my sed version needs to backslash the `+` not to match it literally and **not** to backslash the `|` (it doesn't mean "alternative" here).

```
sed -e 's/\("[[:alnum:]|]\+|'"$2"'"\) "[[:alnum:] ]*"/\1 "'"$3"'"/g'
```

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful I really appreciate the support.

Answer (score 1):

This is a short script for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

sed "s/|\($1\" \)\"[^\"]*\"/\1\"$2\"/g" $3
```

Usage:  `./script.sh AFFICCheckCtlNo hola text2.txt`

Explanation:

- `"s///g"` replaces texts and passes the variables
- `|\($1\" \)\"[^\"]*\"` matches the right lines. After unescaping and substitution it will look like this `|\(AFFICCheckCtlNo " \)"[^"]*"`
- In the parentheses we capture the part that we want to repeat
- The replacement `\1\"$2\"` consists of the remembered part, like `|AFFICLstRcvdCtlNo"`, and then it adds `"yourstring"`, like `"hola"`